# Why SSH on Ubuntu 18.04 is suddenly defaulting to the diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 key-exchange algorithm?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server to which I normally connect via Putty from Windows 10 Pro (1903) without problems. Recently I am getting a warning from Putty that "The first key-exchange algorithm supported by the server is **diffie-hellman-group1-sha1**, which is below the configured warning threshold."

I initially tried to just continue but to my great surprise I am getting an **Access Denied** when I enter my password.

Now I am given to understand that this kex is considered legacy and or weak/insecure. I want to understand what changed/could have changed on my server to trigger this given I could connect without this warning?

What can I do (if anything) to reset my server to whatever it was using before this problem? I already tried reinstalling the **openssh-server** and **client** to no avail. I tried adding a **KexAlgorithms** line in the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file but that causes ssh to not start.

I understand I can move that kex up above the warning line in Putty to make the warning go away but I don't want to do that and like I mentioned above even without the warning I am getting an **Access denied** at login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, this sounds like something changed in PuTTY (upgrade or whatnot).

PuTTY is warning that the server is offering a weak key exchange method.  Since the client will choose the highest method it supports, I don't really see the danger here.

You're probably getting access denied because the PuTTY is aborting the key exchange process and the server won't allow you to login with a password.

I'd recommend dumping PuTTY completely and installing Ubuntu under WSL on your laptop. Then you'll have a full featured OpenSSH client.   You can then do an ssh with -vvvv and see exactly what is being negotiated/exhanged.

EDIT:  One thing you might want to verify is that you're actually connecting to the right IP address?  Or that some other device isn't using the same IP as the Ubuntu server.  As per further research that option shouldn't be offerred by the Ubuntu server since 16.04.

Comment: There are also various builds of OpenSSH that run natively in Windows, and [Windows 10 provides one of them as an optional feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), which might already be installed and, if not, can be installed. This `ssh` command is typically located at `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` (where `C:` is replaced with the actual system drive letter if different).

Comment: @EliahKagan Looking at that path on my PC seems to indicate that that installation is in place.

Comment: @Marc Runkel The part I want to understand is why the server (assuming when we say server we mean the ubuntu server?) is offering a weak key exchange method in the first place?

Comment: So it looks like according to this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#OpenSSH_7.2p2 that diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 is disabled at runtime.   So no idea why your Ubuntu server is offerring that.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked the question but yes there seemed to be another device with the same IP on the network and the issue was resolved by requesting for a new IP address for my server.